# How to update a state of infinite nested array in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, nested, use-state

This is exactly what result I'm expecting to have.

```
{
    category: 'Vehicle',
    subCategory: [
      {
        list_name: 'car',
        nest_name: 'brand',
        nest_list: [
          {
            list_name: 'tesla',
            nest_name: 'model',
            nest_list: [
              { list_name: 'model X', nest_name: '', nest_list: [] },
              { list_name: 'model Y', nest_name: '', nest_list: [] },
            ],
          },
          {
            list_name: 'mercedes',
            nest_name: 'model',
            nest_list: [
              { list_name: 'B class', nest_name: '', nest_list: [] },
              { list_name: 'C class', nest_name: '', nest_list: [] },
              { list_name: 'CLA', nest_name: '', nest_list: [] },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        list_name: 'truck',
        nest_name: 'brand',
        nest_list: [
          {
            list_name: 'iveco',
            nest_name: 'model',
            nest_list: [
              {
                list_name: 'astira',
                nest_name: 'type',
                nest_list: [
                  { list_name: 'single', nest_name: '', nest_list: [] },
                  { list_name: 'double', nest_name: '', nest_list: [] },
                ],
              },
              {
                list_name: 'magirus',
                nest_name: '',
                nest_list: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    description: 'All types of vehicles are categorized under this category.',
  },
```

A description of what I want to do:

I will have a `useState` which will contain the category like the following:

```
// This is the initia state of the category
const initialStateCategory = {
  category: '',
  subCategory: [],
  description: '',
};

// initial state of nested list
const initialStateNestedList = {
  list_name: '',
  nest_name: '',
  nest_list: [],
};

const [category, setCategory] = useState(initialStateCategory);

// And now whenever I click the pushSubCategory button this gets called

const pushSubCategory = () => {
    setCategory({
      ...category,
      subCategory: [...category.subCategory, { ...initialStateNestedList }],
    });
  };
// And it works as it is expected.
```

But the problem is whenever I get deeper to update the `setCategory` state like to push a nested list to the inner nest_list.

And the idea is like this:

There will be a pushNestedList button and whenever I click that button a new nest_list will be added to a specific array.

For Example, Pushing this

```
{ list_name: 'model 3', nest_name: '', nest_list: [] },
```

To

```
SubCategory[0].nest_list[0].nest_list
```

This means it's pushing the above object to the CAR subcategory TESLA Brand.

So if anyone has any solutions or recommendations you are welcome.  I have wasted 3 days figuring out this and didn't solve it yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "But the problem is whenever I get deeper to update the setCategory state like to push a nested list to the inner nest_list."? Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: In short, the problem is in updating the inner nested arrays. Ex, How can I update, 
 subCategory[0].nest_list[0].list_name
which is currently Tesla to something else like Toyota?

Answer (score 0):

I created a small demo for your intended(?) use case.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4943ze?file=src/App.js

You could describe the question as "**How to update the object's property at specific depth**?" or something.

And I suppose you want to control the state as desired, so it includes 'update' specific object as well as 'push' item to the specific array.

The demo might be incomplete but I think it would give you some hint.
The point is

1. Find what you want to update, or push to.
2. replace it using `splice` or `push`
3. setState as new object

```js
export default function App() {
  const initialStateCategory = {
    category: '',
    subCategory: [],
    description: '',
  };

  const [category, setCategory] = useState(initialStateCategory);

  /**
   * @categoryName
   * @item new item
   * @replace object's list_name filed that you want to update
   */
  const updateBrand = (categoryName, item, replace) => {
    const old = { ...category };

    // find the target cateogry to update
    const idx = old.subCategory.findIndex(
      (category) => category.list_name === categoryName
    );
    if (idx < 0) return; // quit when not found
    const update = old.subCategory[idx];
    console.log(update);

    // replace the target brand
    if (replace) {
      const brandIdx = update.nest_list.findIndex(
        (b) => b.list_name === replace
      );
      if (brandIdx > -1) {
        update.nest_list.splice(brandIdx, 1, item);
      }
    }

    // or if you intend to 'push' to the array
    else {
      update.nest_list.push(item);
    }

    const newSubCategory = old.subCategory.splice(idx, 1, update);
    const updated = { ...old, subCategory: newSubCategory };

    setCategory(updated);
  };

  const updateCategory = (item, replace) => {
    const old = { ...category };
    if (replace) {
      const idx = old.subCategory.findIndex((c) => c.list_name === replace);
      if (idx > -1) {
        old.subCategory.splice(idx, 1, item);
      }
    } else {
      old.subCategory.push(item);
    }
    setCategory(old);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => updateCategory(car)}>+ car</button>
      <button onClick={() => updateCategory(truck)}>+ truck</button>
      <button onClick={() => updateCategory(bike, 'truck')}>
        - truck + bike
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => updateBrand('car', tesla)}>+ car.tesla</button>
      <button onClick={() => updateBrand('car', toyota)}>+ car.toyota</button>
      <button onClick={() => updateBrand('car', toyota, 'tesla')}>
        - car.tesla + car.toyota
      </button>
      <div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(category, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Finally, I think this kind of state in a complex architecture is kind of hard to maintain, so you might be better reconsider the app's design, if possible.